# Data after die()

Tags: plugin-development

I created a cron for an import and i pointed it to a Craft controller. Everything is working as expected but im getting a strange output after the die() call. It is something starting with

```
Import finished<script type="text/javascript">

/*<![CDATA[*/
if (typeof(console) == 'object')
{
        console.groupCollapsed("Application Log");

                console.groupCollapsed("GET info");
        console.log("[20:51:21.230][info][application]\n");
        console.groupEnd();
        console.groupCollapsed("Info om informasjonskapsel");
        console.log("[20:51:21.230][info][application]\n$_GET=array (\n  \'p\' => \'actions/garp/cron/changeStock\',\n)\n\n");
        console.groupEnd();
        console.groupCollapsed("SERVER info");
        console.log("[20:51:21.230][info][application]\n$_SERVER=array (\n  \'REDIRECT_HTTPS\' => \'on\',\n  \'REDIRECT_SSL_TLS_SNI\' => \'staging.alfa.rrdev.co\',\n  \'REDIRECT_STATUS\' => \'200\',\n  \'HTTPS\' => \'on\',\n  \'SSL_TLS_SNI\' => \'staging.alfa.rrdev.co\',\n  \'HTTP_USER_AGENT\' => \'Wget/1.15 (linux-gnu)\',\n  \'HTTP_ACCEPT\' => \'*/*\',\n  \'HTTP_HOST\' => \'staging.alfa.rrdev.co\',\n  \'HTTP_CONNECTION\' => \'Keep-Alive\',\n  \'PATH\' => \'/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin\',\n  \'SERVER_SIGNATURE\' => \'<address>Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at staging.alfa.rrdev.co Port 443<\/address>\n\',\n  \'SERVER_SOFTWARE\' => \'Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)\',\n  \'SERVER_NAME\' => \'staging.alfa.rrdev.co\',\n  \'SERVER_ADDR\' => \'172.31.34.161\',\n  \'SERVER_PORT\' => \'443\',\n  \'REMOTE_ADDR\' => \'54.76.237.6\',\n  \'DOCUMENT_ROOT\' => \'/var/www/alfa/public\',\n  \'REQUEST_SCHEME\' => \'https\',\n  \'CONTEXT_PREFIX\' => \'\',\n  \'CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT\' => \'/var/www/alfa/public\',\n  \'SERVER_ADMIN\' => \'[no address given]\',\n  \'SCRIPT_FILENAME\' => \'/var/www/alfa/public/index.php\',\n  \'REMOTE_PORT\' => \'51921\',\n  \'REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING\' => \'p=actions/garp/cron/changeStock\',\n  \'REDIRECT_URL\' => \'/actions/garp/cron/changeStock\',\n  \'GATEWAY_INTERFACE\' => \'CGI/1.1\',\n  \'SERVER_PROTOCOL\' => \'HTTP/1.1\',\n  \'REQUEST_METHOD\' => \'GET\',\n  \'QUERY_STRING\' => \'p=actions/garp/cron/changeStock\',\n  \'REQUEST_URI\' => \'/actions/garp/cron/changeStock\',\n  \'SCRIPT_NAME\' => \'/index.php\',\n  \'PHP_SELF\' => \'/index.php\',\n  \'REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT\' => 1412369481.227,\n  \'REQUEST_TIME\' => 1412369481,\n)");
        console.groupEnd();
```

Code (actionChangeStock) ends with

```
    if (craft()->httpSession->get('garpfailed')) {
        echo "Import failed";
    } else {
        echo "Import finished";
    }
    die();
}
```

and cron call is

```
wget -O /home/ubuntu/cronStock https://domain.com/actions/garp/cron/changeStock
```

Is this expected? Im getting a 9mb file when i should get only Import failed or Import finished.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's [devMode](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/config-settings#devMode) output (usually gets sent to your browser's console).

If you want to run your plugin in devMode, add this to your plugin's `init()` method:

```
craft()->log->removeRoute('WebLogRoute');
craft()->log->removeRoute('ProfileLogRoute');
```

And it will get rid of the extra output.

Comment: To get rid of this without the init() changes can i change the devMode to false for this environment?

Comment: That'll work, too.